# How to set input field from Autocomplete results as non editable?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am setting an input value with the selected result from Autocomplete as follows.

```
$("#referenceinput").autocomplete( 
{
source: function(request, response) 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: searchURL,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
             searchStr: request.term
        },
        success: function(data){
            response($.map(data.indexResult, function(item){
                return {label: item}
            }));
        }
    });
},
minLength: 3,
select: function(event, ui)
{
    $("#referenceinput").val(ui.item);
}
});
```

My referenceInput field is the following.

```
<input id = "referenceinput" type = "text" width= "140px"/>
```

How to set referenceinput value from Autocomplete results as non editable but can delete (similar to "Tags" field in stackoverflow while posting a question)?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rMYxU/1/ ?

Comment: Andrew, Thanks for the reply. For the same example you have given, when we select Google from Autocomplete results, I want the input field to be populated with Google but the characters should not be editable. We should only allow user to clear/delete the whole word in input field, Similar to "Tags" field in stackoverflow while posting a question.

Comment: Did you get any answer?