# Non editable jQuery auto-complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are trying to implement non-editable jQuery auto-complete. For example when user selects value from auto-complete they not able to modify it. But when they press backspace old value is deleted and again they can select new   value from auto-complete.
We know there is lot's of plugin for this, But we don't want to use any plugin.

Here is our jsfiddle for normal auto-complete.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/9R4cV/)

Here is the plugin which which has this functionality.

[plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

Our Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo",
        "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"
    ];

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: aTags
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />
```

Comment: in plugin they are adding `li` elements which they are able to remove in backspace but you are adding strings which by default won't go by single backspace.you have to write a event to clear it.

Comment: Same type question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131080/how-to-set-input-field-from-autocomplete-results-as-non-editable

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:** Try catching backspace then set the field to blank.If you want to set the field `readonly` on selection,you can do it in select of `autocomplete`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo",
    "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"
];

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: aTags,
    select: function () {
     $('#tags').prop("readonly",true);
      }
});

$('#tags').bind('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#tags').prop("value","");
        $('#tags').prop("readonly",false);
    }
});

});


</script>
<style>

#tags:focus {
 border:1px solid #0000ff;
}

</style>
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />
```

[FIDDLE WITH YOUR ANGULAR SCRIPT](http://jsfiddle.net/suchit/hesp5acw/2/)

Comment: But here user can modify selected value. for example if you select 'ask' then  you can modify it. So its editable.

Comment: But you bind the backspace event of document to clear the value. Its not correct.

Comment: @RenuThakur i have made the edit for tags only see now.

Comment: Thanks. Its good. But can you see this http://jsfiddle.net/codemonkeytony/3ew5h6bf/7/

see you cant edit the old value. Now i trying to  mix-up your code with this

Comment: jsfiddle.net/codemonkeytony/3ew5h6bf/7 Its not correct. But i am also trying to customize this too

Comment: Please explain why you can't just use <select>.

Comment: @СӏаџԁеМаятіи i did not get you .can you elaborate your question.

Comment: @Suchit Here we have another problem. You and i know that backspace clear the value. But user don't know until cursor is in text-box.

Comment: Why can the html element <select> not be used? If there are too many options then there could be a select for category and anotherone for subcategories. Another question is why you don't just validate the input to make sure the input is one of the given options. If not use setCustomValidity(...). This way you could keep it accessible.

Comment: Ohh you are talking about drop down list. But we need auto-complete, Because we have thousand of crors data and we cant show them in drop don list.

Comment: @RenuThakur see if adding a style helps.

Comment: Yes, trying to do that.

Comment: @RenuThakur your fiddle will work if you add <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> in external resources.

Comment: Yes. thanks. i forgot to update. And our senior guy dont want to add new angular.js  So now again i modified code. And its working correctly. check this now http://jsfiddle.net/Yt72H/407/

Comment: @RenuThakur yes  looks like it is working fine .do you have any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this. It's as per my requirement. May be it will help some-one.

[Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Yt72H/410/)

HTML:-

```
<input id="field" type="text" placeholder="test" value="" size="50" />
<div id="output">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var readOnlyLength = $('#field').val().length;
var tmpFlag=true;
var aTags = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];


 $( "#field" ).autocomplete({
    source: aTags,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
   tmpFlag=false;
   }
});
$('#output').text(readOnlyLength);

$('#field').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
var $field = $(this);

 if(event.which==8){
    $('#field').val('');
                   tmpFlag=true;

}

console.log(tmpFlag);
if(tmpFlag==false)
if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
    && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)|| (this.selectionStart <= readOnlyLength) ||(this.selectionStart > readOnlyLength) 
    || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
     event.preventDefault();
}


});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
var aTags = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: aTags
    });
    $( "#tags" ).blur(function(){
        var tag = $(this).val();
        if(jQuery.inArray(tag,aTags) == -1){
          // the element is not in the array
           $( "#tags" ).val(''); 
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/490/)

Here in `blur function` I check the input value whether in the array, if not I clear the input field.

Comment: Sorry, but you can modify selected value.

Comment: @RenuThakur, yes you can, but the modified value is not in the array, it become cleared in `blur` function.

Comment: Yes, But my requirement is user is not able to modify selected value.